# Evaluate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\, 2^{-k}$

Tags: summation, closed-form

> By sum properties, prove that: $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\, 2^{-k}=2^{-n}(-6+3\cdot 2^{1+n}-4n-n^2)$$

Progress so far: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\,2^{-k}  =   1\cdot (1/2) + 4\cdot (1/4) + 9\cdot (1/8) + 16\cdot (1/16) + 25\cdot (1/32) + 36\cdot (1/64)+\dots +n^2\cdot (1/2^n)$$

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Include your best attempt also in the question...

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}k^2$.
$$
\begin{align*}
S(n+1) &= S(n)+2^{-n-1}(n+1)^2\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}2^{-k}k^2\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=2}^{n+1}2^{-k}k^2\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{-k-1}(k+1)^2\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}(k+1)^2\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}(k^2 + 2k + 1)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}2k + \sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(S(n) + 2\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}k + \sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
Now use the same technique to find $A(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}$ is a geometric series. Then finally solve the above equation for $S(n)$.
$$
\begin{align*}
A(n+1) &= A(n) + 2^{-n-1}(n+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} 2^{-k}k\\
&= \frac{1}{2}+ \sum_{k=2}^{n+1}2^{-k}k\\
&= \frac{1}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{-k-1}(k+1)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{-k}(k+1)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{-k}k + \sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{-k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\left(A(n) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{-k}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
So now solve for $A(n)$ and finally $S(n)$.