# How can I evaluate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 2^k$?

Tags: summation, proof-explanation

I am trying to evaluate the sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 2^k.
$$
I was following this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504529/evaluate-the-sum-sum-k-1nk2-2-k) and came up with this:
\begin{align*}
   S(n) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 2^k \\
   S(n+1) &= S(n) + \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} k^2 2^k \\
   &= 2 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 2^k \\
   &= 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)^2 2^{k+1} \\
   &= 2 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k(k^2 + 2k + 2) \\
   &= 2 + 2 \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 2^k + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k2^k + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k \right) \\
&= 2 + 2 \left( S(n) + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k2^k + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k \right)
\end{align*}

And this is where I'm stuck. I plugged it into WolframAlpha and apparently the answer is $S(n) = 2(2^nn^2 - 2^{n+1}n+3\cdot 2^n-3)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $S(n+1)\ne S(n)+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k^22^k$, so...

Comment: The state-of-the-art trick is by differentiating the polynomial $f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n x^k = \frac{1 - x^{n + 1}}{1 - x}$ for several times.

Comment: Although there are some mistakes on the first lines, your fourth line mysteriously is correct. My hint for you is: you probably know how to compute $\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k$. A next step would be to use the strategy above to find an expression for $\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k$. From there, you can use your final expression.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688659/induction-proof-k2-times-2k

Comment: @GerryMyerson Nicely spotted, but this is not the same. No induction here.

Comment: @ams, the title of the question here is, "How can I evaluate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^nk^22^k$?" The link answers the question in the title.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm assuming OP would like to know how to get there without knowing the result beforehand.

Comment: @ams, you may be right. OP should edit the title in such a way as to reflect what he/she really wants to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

As

$$
S_n(x) = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}
$$

we have

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k^2x^k = x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}S(x)\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=0}^nk^2 x^k=x\sum_{k=0}^nk^2x^{k-1}$

$=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^nkx^k=x\frac{d}{dx}x\sum_{k=0}^nkx^{k-1}$

$=x\frac{d}{dx}x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^nx^k$

$=x\frac{d}{dx}x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$

I'll let you do the calculus and evaluate the expression for $x=2$.

Note that I started the sum at $k=0$, but it doesn't matter since the added term is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the method you provided in the link, then a corrected derivation would look something like:
\begin{align}
S(n+1) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^22^k   \\
&= 2 + \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} k^22^k \\
&= 2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (i+1)^22^{i+1} \\
&= 2 + 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^22^i + 2\sum_{i=1}^ni2^i + \sum_{i=1}^n2^i\right) \\
&= 2 + 2\left(S(n) + 2\sum_{i=1}^ni2^i + \sum_{i=1}^n2^i\right).
\end{align}
Then by using the fact that $S(n+1) = S(n) + (n+1)^22^{n+1}$ we can solve for $S(n)$. You may recognise $\sum_{i=1}^n2^i$ as the finite sum of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) (this has a standard formula). The sum $\sum_{i=1}^ni2^i$ is similar in form to our original problem and thus a similar argument can be used (i.e. we take $A(n) = \sum_{i=1}^ni2^i$ and proceed similarly).

I would not use this method myself and instead use the method demonstrated in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

*An easy trick.*

Consider
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 x^k=\sum_{k=1}^n (k(k-1)+k) x^k=x^2\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1) x^{k-2}+x\sum_{k=1}^n k x^{k-1}$$ that is to say
$$S_n=x^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n  x^{k} \right)''+x\left(\sum_{k=1}^n  x^{k} \right)'$$